# Policy-based routing - neither rules nor routes get picked-up by CentOS 7.6.1810

Tags: centos, linux-networking, networkmanager, policy-routing

I have 2 VLANs over a bonded connection I can't get to work with policy-based-routing. Actually I can make them work manually, but I'm unable to persist the configuration in order to survive reboots. I've read a dozen of articles, tutorials, how-tos and official docs. I'm listing just the relevant entries from the connection list here:

```
# nmcli con
NAME                        UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
bond0 slave 1               ...-91ef-...                          ethernet  eno1
bond0 slave 2               ...-242e-...                          ethernet  eno2
Bond connection bond0       ...-0fbe-...                          bond      bond0
VLAN connection bond0.3410  ...-3ebd-...                          vlan      bond0.3410
VLAN connection bond0.3411  ...-91a9-...                          vlan      bond0.3411
```

The new tables have been added to the `rt_tables` list.

```
# cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
1       3410
2       3411
```

Then I've created custom rules for both VLAN interfaces:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-bond0.3410
iif bond0.3410 table 3410
from 10.129.240.0/23 table 3410
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-bond0.3411
iif bond0.3411 table 3411
from 10.129.242.0/24 table 3411
```

And defined the wished routing rules.

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-bond0.3410
10.129.240.0/23 dev bond0.3410 scope link table 3410
default via 10.129.241.254 dev bond0.3410 table 3410
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-bond0.3411
10.129.242.0/24 dev bond0.3411 scope link table 3411
default via 10.129.242.254 dev bond0.3411 table 3411
```

What bothers me is that *none* of the rules and routes get picked up. I've tried restarting the networking service `systemctl restart network`, rebooting the node, bringing up the connections via `nmcli con up <con_name>`.

All these modifications brought no change:

```
# ip route list
10.129.240.0/23 dev bond0.3410 proto kernel scope link src 10.129.240.1 metric 400
10.129.242.0/24 dev bond0.3411 proto kernel scope link src 10.129.242.1 metric 401

# ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

The only thing I'm sure of is that the custom routing tables `3410` and `3411` exist (as no error is thrown when listing routes by the table, e.g. `ip route list table 3411`).

I should also say that when I'm running the entries manually (e.g. `ip route add default <ip> dev <dev> table <table>`) then the entries take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using NetworkManager for your network management (as opposite to /etc/init.d/network) then you need NetworkManager-dispatcher-routing-rules package.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I indeed read about it, but I forgot to ensure that this was in place after I rebuilt my environment the last time.